# Search string in DB Table by its prefix

Tags: php, mysql, search, prefix

I have a telephone numbers database.
There are 2 tables; TEL_PREFIX & SUBSCRIBER.

TEL_PREFIX has a column PREFIX and SUBSCRIBER has column NUMBER.

the relation is many to one between SUBSCRIBER and TEL_PREFIX (TEL_PREFIX has many SUBSCRIBER).

Concatenating PREFIX with NUMBER generate the real phone number of the subscriber.

Example:
`PREFIX=011442` and `NUMBER=3452` with relation between these 2 records, will generate the real number 0114423452

**my question:**

I have the full number as input (ex: 0114443452), and there is no record in SUBSCRIBER table with number 3452 and I want to get the PREFIX record this handle that number.

P.S: prefix length is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.
I used [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)
and my query will be:

```
select * from tel_prefix
where locate(tel_prefix.prefix, phone) > 0
```

where `phone` is my input.

Do you have any comments over using `LOCATE`.